# Socket.IO emits inside emit aren't firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an emit where I'm trying to set the current state of the game, and then fire a few more emit after that. For some reason, none of the subsequent emits are working. I am new to Socket.IO so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the emit within my app.js:

```
socket.emit('set_game_state', 'Lobby', () => {
            socket.emit('reconnect');
            socket.emit('set_cookie', player);
            socket.emit('player', player);
        });
```

I've tried some console logs inside of the function as well and they don't print out.

Here is my angular front end:

```
this._gameService.socket.on('set_game_state', (newGameState: any) => {
  this.currentGameState = newGameState;
});
```

Comment: `socket.emit()` with a callback requires [server acknowledgement](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args). What exactly do you think it will do?

Comment: `io.sockets.emit();` does it take callback?

Comment: if it is server api please look at https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#serversockets

Comment: I'm using angular as a front end for this. Would you happen to know any examples of how to acknowledge the server? I've updated the question to show what my current client code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying my front-end angular code with the following and it worked:

```
this._gameService.socket.on('set_game_state', (newGameState: any) => {
  this.currentGameState = newGameState;
  this.gameStateAck = () => ack();
  this.gameStateAck();
});
```